# How to write long sentences in math mode

Tags: equations, formatting

[image]I would like to write these sentences aligned by \subseteq. But they didn't fit on the page and I had to reduce the font size. The problem is that this part was disproportionate to the rest of the text.

Is there a better way for me to write this? This is my code:

```
\begin{gather*}
    \tiny{
    \begin{aligned}
        L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1) &\subseteq (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\\[5pt](L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^{\boldsymbol{*}} &\subseteq ((L(0)\cup L(1))^*)^{\boldsymbol{*}}\\[5pt]
        (L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^* &\subseteq (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\\[5pt]
        (L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^*\boldsymbol{L(0)L(0)L(0)(L(0) \cup L(1))^*} &\subseteq  (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\boldsymbol{L(0)L(0)L(0)(L(0) \cup L(1))^*}
    \end{aligned}}
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: `\tiny{` size commands like `\tiny` do not take an argument, so the `{` here is wrong, and they may not be used in math mode, so it should be before `begin{gather}` (but it would be unreadably small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you'll like the way this looks, but you could use `mathtools` and `\shortintertext` to split the long line over three lines, left-justify the first and right-justify  the third:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
        L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1) &\subseteq (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\\[5pt](L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^{\boldsymbol{*}} &\subseteq ((L(0)\cup L(1))^*)^{\boldsymbol{*}}\\[5pt]
        (L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^* &\subseteq (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\\[5pt]
\shortintertext{$
        (L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^*\boldsymbol{L(0)L(0)L(0)(L(0) \cup L(1))^*}$}
         &\subseteq
\shortintertext{\hfill $(L(0)\cup L(1))^*\boldsymbol{L(0)L(0)L(0)(L(0) \cup L(1))^*}$}\\[-2\baselineskip]
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break the lines within the alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
        L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1) &\subseteq (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\\[5pt](L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^{\boldsymbol{*}} &\subseteq ((L(0)\cup L(1))^*)^{\boldsymbol{*}}\\[5pt]
        (L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup L(0)L(0)L(1))^* &\subseteq (L(0)\cup L(1))^*\\[5pt]
  \begin{multlined}[b]
    (L(1) \cup L(0)L(1) \cup{} L(0)L(0)L(1))^*\\
    \boldsymbol{L(0)L(0)L(0)(L(0) \cup L(1))^*}
  \end{multlined}
         &
  \begin{multlined}[t]
  \subseteq  (L(0)\cup  L(1))^*\\
  \boldsymbol{L(0)L(0)L(0)(L(0) \cup L(1))^*}
 \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\noindent X\dotfill X


\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't want to break the lines like that because I didn't want to separate the concatenations (I wanted this part (L(1) U L(0)L(1) U L(0)L(0)L(1))*L(0 )L(0)L(0)(L(0) U L(1))* were together/one immediately after the other, and the part (L(0) U L(1))*L(0)L(0)L(0) (L(0) U L(1))* also). Is there any way to do this without shortening the font? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: I meant I didn't want to separate the concatenations between languages.@David Carlisle

Comment: @B612 sorry I don't know what you mean (and you didn't provide a test file in your question so I had to guess page size and fonts).I was originally going to break the lines at the `\cup` rather than the`^*` but I couldn't work out the intended meaning so wasn't sure what was best, but you can break the line wherever you like.  Obviously if you want it on one line the only choice is to have a smaller font or larger page, and your question gives no indicaion of your current font or page sizes.